# Searching a line by date in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

So, i have this CSV file and i need to do a program that can search through the CSV with the user inserting a date (all the dates are values in the csv). Honestly i'm completely lost on what to do, and if anyone of you could help me it would be great!
CSV line example:

**6288,Ossidi di Azoto,µg/m³,551,Arconate v. DeGasperi,182,MI,Arconate,20/01/1999**

this is the code i've done so far using examples online but i don't think anything of it is near to being right

```
public String ricercaCsv(int CercaIndice, String CercaStringa, String CercaData) throws IOException {
        String RigaRisultato = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\leona\\IdeaProjects\\PrjAria\\src\\Aria.csv"));
        String linea;
        while ( (linea = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            String[] values = linea.split(",");
            if(values[CercaIndice].equals(CercaStringa)) {
                RigaRisultato = linea;
                break;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return RigaRisultato;


    }
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: brother, the page you sent me has nothing to do with it. There it clearly says that you can't put "can anyone help me?" in the post title, and i didn't lmao.  I'm a student yes, and need a bit of help on why the code i've made doesn't work lol

Comment: That's a semicolon-separated file. You're splitting on commas. You won't find anything unless you split on semicolons. Watch your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not your brother. "can anyone help me" and your "... and if anyone of you could help me it would be great!" is exactly the same, only other words. It's a typical "I am lost. I don't know what to do" question. Please don't take it personally but these kind of questions are off-topic here. You need a mentor or teacher or  lot more work to improve your question. You show us a random code snippet you found in the internet without a detail explanation of the problem you have with it. In essence you want us to write the code for you.

Comment: What if there are multiple lines having the same date?

Comment: Oh no yeah since i wrote the example manually i typed the semicolon, but in the file it's a comma.

Comment: There are not multiple lines with the same date

Comment: Sorry Vanje, but i don't want anyone to write the code for me, in Just wanted someone Who could point out what i'm doing wrong with this code adn what could work. If i didn't include "can anyone help me" and Just said "this thing doesn't work and i don't know why" would anything change?

Comment: @LeonardoRosini, I added some solutions to your question. If you learn how to parse files, follow Mykong. If you are open to a ready solution, move with OpenCSV and read line by line. 

If it is a proper CSV is usually separated by commas and has the same amount of columns. It can be a CSV-like file with a random number of columns - you better write your parser. Note, as every cell is `String,` you need to convert it to Date or before comparison. This will be useful if you decide to find rows in a date range.

Answer (score 0):

Mykong answered in his [article](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).

**Part 1:**

My personal approach will be to use the external library if you can:

```
  try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"))) {
      String[] lineInArray;
      while ((lineInArray = reader.readNext()) != null) {
          System.out.println(lineInArray[0] + lineInArray[1] + "etc...");
      }
  }
```

with

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use something different from Maven, see syntax for your project builder on [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.6).

**Part 2:**
Ideally, when you know that you are looking for the date `10/10/1999`, I recommend transform these dates (it should be assumingly the same column all the time).

Possible example,

```
String date = "10/10/1999";
SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
Date result = sdt.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right your csv lines end with the date column, and you are searching for a line which ends with the date enterd by the user. So you don't need to split the lines at all and just use `Strings.endsWith()` for each line to check for a match.

So the easiest solution would be to use the methods from the java.nio package to read a file and filter the line you need. Here are three ways:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

 ....

public String ricercaCsv_1(String CercaData) throws IOException {
    final String fileName = "C:\\Users\\leona\\IdeaProjects\\PrjAria\\src\\Aria.csv";
    final Stream<String> fileContent = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
    return fileContent.filter(line -> line.endsWith(CercaData)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

example usage to search by name for the above method:

```
String result = ricercaCsv_1("19/05/2022");
```

If you want to stick with your approach using `BufferedReader`

```
public String ricercaCsv_2(String CercaData) throws IOException {
    String RigaRisultato = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\leona\\IdeaProjects\\PrjAria\\src\\Aria.csv"));
    String linea;
    while ( (linea = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        if(linea.endsWith(CercaData)) {
            RigaRisultato = linea;
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return RigaRisultato;
}
```

example usage to search by name for the above method:

```
String result = ricercaCsv_2(8, "19/05/2022");
```

If you want to reuse your method and be able to search by any column by just passing the column index, something like below should work:

```
public String ricercaCsv_3(int CercaIndice, String CercaStringa) throws IOException {
    String RigaRisultato = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\leona\\IdeaProjects\\PrjAria\\src\\Aria.csv"));
    String linea;
    while ( (linea = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        String[] values = linea.split(",");
        if(values[CercaIndice].equals(CercaStringa)) {
            RigaRisultato = linea;
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return RigaRisultato;
}
```

example usage to search by name for the above method:

```
String result = ricercaCsv_3(8, "19/05/2022");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily search a line by date in a CSV file with [esProc SPL](https://github.com/SPLWare/esProc)(a java based open-source scripting language for data processing),for example:

```
...
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareStatement("==file(\"data.csv\";\"UTF-8\").import@c().select(_9==\"23/01/1999\")");
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
...
```

with

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.scudata.esproc/esproc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scudata.esproc</groupId>
    <artifactId>esproc</artifactId>
    <version>20220402</version>
</dependency>
```